# Firefox onkeypress with ctrl key

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom-events

I have an input, on which I want specific behavior when a character is inserted, but I want the default behavior on shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Here's the html:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="onInputKeyPress(event)" />
```

and the JavaScript:

```
function onInputKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.charCode >= 32) {
        // do some processing here       
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This works fine in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox. This is because when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, the `onkeypress` doesn't get called on IE and Chrome, but it does get called in Firefox.

So I tried to insert this code to the start of my handler:

```
if (event.ctrlKey) {
    // leave default behavior for shortcuts
    return true;
}
```

Now my custom processing doesn't get called when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, but the shortcut still doesn't work (the text doesn't get copied into the clipboard).

Should I do something more to force Firefox to do the default action?

Comment: Can we see more of your code or a reduced testcase? This should work the way you describe. Note: if you only target fairly recent browsers, it should probably use the “input” event instead of “keypress”.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert the rest of the code is irrelevant for this question. The code is the same as in the example I provided, except there is some processing instead of the comment `// do some processing here ` and that code doesn't even get called when my problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question, I think this is what you are looking for:

I suggest you use this to copy to clipboard:

```js
var clipboard = require("sdk/clipboard");
clipboard.set("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
var contents = clipboard.get();
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/clipboard

Comment: Thanks but this is not the way to go for me.... I need to preserve all the shortcuts like ctrl+c, ctr+v, ctr+a and so on... it doesn't make sense to do all this "manually".

Comment: I see. I don't think that this will overide default though... If that is what you mean